# How can I allow for returns in Django form inputs?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a form that accepts texts and can save it but when I put in

"Hello

World"

it gets saved and comes out as **"Hello World"** without the return. How can I allow for the return to be saved?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add **`|linebreaksbr`** in django template for it to show returns and line breaks within the data

```html
<p>{{ user_input_stuff|linebreaksbr }}</p>
```